# Renaming the return fields of a SQL query with string variables?

Tags: sql, dynamic-programming, dynamic-sql, dolphindb

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
symbol  date    price   volume
GE  2017.01.03  31.82   2,300
GE  2017.01.03  31.69   3,500
GE  2017.01.04  31.92   3,700
GE  2017.01.04  31.8    2,100
GE  2017.01.04  31.75   1,200
GE  2017.01.04  31.76   4,600
MSFT    2017.01.03  63.12   1,800
MSFT    2017.01.03  62.58   3,800
MSFT    2017.01.04  63.12   6,400
MSFT    2017.01.04  62.77   4,200
MSFT    2017.01.04  61.86   2,300
MSFT    2017.01.04  62.3    6,800
F   2017.01.03  12.46   4,200
F   2017.01.03  12.59   5,600
F   2017.01.04  13.24   8,900
F   2017.01.04  13.41   2,300
F   2017.01.04  13.36   6,300
F   2017.01.04  13.17   9,600
```

I want to perform some kind of aggregation (say, `avg(price)` or `sum(volume)`) by date over all MSFT records. Meanwhile, I want to rename the returned field with the string (like “avgPrice“ or “sumVol“) that is passed in through a variable. Any ideas how I could do this?

Thanks!

*P.S. The table can be created with the following script:*

```
symbol = take(`GE,6) join take(`MSFT,6) join take(`F,6)
date=take(take(2017.01.03,2) join take(2017.01.04,4), 18)
price=31.82 31.69 31.92 31.8  31.75 31.76 63.12 62.58 63.12 62.77 61.86 62.3 12.46 12.59 13.24 13.41 13.36 13.17
volume=2300 3500 3700 2100 1200 4600 1800 3800 6400 4200 2300 6800 4200 5600 8900 2300 6300 9600
t1 = table(symbol, date, price, volume);
t1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use aliases as follows:

```sql
SELECT AVG(price) AS avgPrice, SUM(volume) AS sumVol
FROM yourTable
WHERE symbol = 'MSFT';
```

If you instead wanted to view the average price or volume sum over all symbols, or at least more than one symbol, then use an aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT symbol, AVG(price) AS avgPrice, SUM(volume) AS sumVol
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY symbol;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [metaprogramming technique in DolphinDB](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/meta_programming.md).

Try this:

```
name1 = `avgPrice
name2 = `sumVol
whereConditions = [<symbol=`MSFT>,<volume>x>]
sql(select=(sqlColAlias(<avg(price)>, name1), sqlColAlias(<sum(volume)>, name2)), from=t1, groupBy=sqlCol(`date)).eval()
```

The output:

```
date    avgPrice    sumVol
2017.01.03  35.71   21,200
2017.01.04  35.8717 58,400
```